# Update a custom attribute in AWS Cognito User using Lambda Trigger in Google Signup

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a NextJS project. There I'm using both username password signup and google signup (federated signup).

In username password signup, I'm able to pass an attribute 'custom:title' with value 'new' as follows:

```
await Auth.signUp({
    username: customUsername,
    password,
    attributes: { 
       email, 
       name,
       "custom:title": "manager"
    }   
  })
```

My problem is how can I do the same in federated sign up (signup using google) flow in below:

```
await Auth.federatedSignin({
    provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentifyProvider.Google  
  })
```

The reason for passing above attribute during the signup is that, based on the value of `custom:title`, I need to add the user to a different user group in `post confirmation lambda trigger` in AWS Cognito User Pool. For example, if the user who is signup using google has the attribute `custom:title` with value 'manager', then I want to add him to the user group called `managers`. If the user who signup using google does not have value of the attribute `custom:title`, then I'm adding him to `employee` user group.

Can somebody please provide a solution/work around for this problem, please?

I'm happy to provide more information/context.

Thank you so much for your help.

Currently, I researched about the possiblities and found 0 results in the internet.

Comment: did you solve this problem?